# transform sql query to Fluentpdo query

Tags: php, mysql, fluentpdo

i have this sql query written in php:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE bank_info SET
                      amount_dollar = amount_dollar +'$amount_dollar'  ,
                      amount_euro = amount_euro + '$amount_euro' ,
                      amount_local = amount_local + '$amount_local'
                      WHERE bank_id = '$bank_id' ");
```

this query works fine, but i want to transform this query using FluentPDO.
i want to use arrays to SET the values .
for example:

```
$table='bank_info'; //table name
$arrVal=array();    //values needs to be SET
$arrVal['amount_dollar = amount_dollar+?']=$amount_dollar;
$arrVal['amount_euro = amount_euro+?']=$amount_euro;
$arrVal['amount_local = amount_local+?']=$amount_local;
$arrWhere=array();  //where condition
$arrWhere['bank_id']=$bank_id;
```

this is the query:

```
$query = $this->pdo->update($table)->set($arrVal)->where($arrWhere);

$query->execute();
```

I think the problem is in the $arrVal, cant find the proper way to SET and add value to the current value for a column in the table. 
I used array to select and get values from the DB/tables for many times so i think the $arrWhere is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

well, found the answer,

for ex.:

This is working for me:

```
$id = 5;
$field = 'stock';
$amount = 1;

$increment = array($field => new FluentLiteral($field.' + '.$amount));

$fpdo->update('products')->set($increment)->where('id', $id)->execute();
```